# How to do circle packing in Raphael?

Tags: raphael

[Link for UI](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~bederson/papers/index.html)

My requirement is to make compatible this chart with lower versions of internet explorers. 
Link for the ui is attached.

Answer (score 0):

That's presumably done in d3--looks [like this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269).

There are two parts to that visualization: calculating the size and position of the circles and actually drawing them. It's very possible that the first part is compatible with IE, or could be made to be so by extending any Array functions that don't make it back that far.

You could take over from there and draw the circle in Raphael, which does work at least back to IE7. I believe that's the idea behind [d34raphael](http://webmonarch.github.io/d34raphael/), a fork of d3. You could try that or do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Chris Wilson.. I appreciate your help. But go through the given link. Drawing the circles are not the problem . but getting that arrangement is my problem.